# Updating sqlite column with value from another databse file

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two database files. One is outdated, the other one fits my new needs. 
I need to update a value of a row with the value from the second file if the timestamp is the same. I opened both files in SQLite Studio and ran the following query :

```
UPDATE user SET acceptedAGB= ( SELECT acceptedAGBFROM oldDB.user WHERE timestamp == oldDB.user.timestamp)
```

The problem is that this sets all values in acceptedAGB to 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ATTACH`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-attach-database/) to connect to the `oldDB` database and `main.user` to qualify your table's column name inside the subquery:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'pathtoyourdatabase/oldDB.db' as oldDB;
UPDATE user 
SET acceptedAGB = ( 
  SELECT t.acceptedAGB 
  FROM oldDB.user t 
  WHERE main.user.timestamp = t.timestamp
);
```

Make sure that the subquery returns only 1 row.